# Why are 'source' and '.' not always the same, when they're supposed to be identical?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I was under the impression that `source` was a synonym for `.` in bash. However, it seems that in the `.profile` file, `source` doesn't work. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlktScWq53o) demonstrates that when `source` is used in `~/.profile` to source a file `foo`, the variable defined in that file is not exported to subsequent shells. However, if instead the file is sourced using `.`, the variable is exported as expected.

Note that when I use `source`, the environment variable does NOT get exported, but when I use `.` it does.

Comment: Lightdm sources .profile in /bin/sh which is dash by default, and dash doesn't have a source command, it is a bash extension (see /usr/sbin/lightdm-session)

Comment: They are the same. Post (pastebin) the contents of all your files, including the one you are sourcing. And what shell are you using ? bash or zsh?

Comment: Please include the explanation in your question so we don't need to go and watch some random youtube video to understand the issue.

Comment: @JasonConti darn, sorry, just saw your comment, happy to delete if you want to post an answer.

Comment: @terdon it's an excellent answer, I wouldn't have put that much effort into it

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please don't close. The OP _knows_ they're supposed to be identical and has found a particular case where they appear not to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are exactly the same, as explained in `man bash`:

```
.  filename [arguments]
source filename [arguments]
    Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell
    environment and return the exit status of the last command executed
    from filename.  If filename does not contain a slash, file names in
    PATH are used to find the directory containing filename.  The file
    searched for in PATH need not be executable.  When bash is not in
    posix mode, the current directory is searched if no file is found in
    PATH.  If the sourcepath option to the shopt builtin command is turned
    off, the PATH is not searched.  If any argu‐ ments are supplied, they
    become the positional parameters when filename is executed.  Otherwise
    the positional parameters are unchanged.  The return status is the
    status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no commands
    are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read.
```

The issue here is that `source` is a *bash* thing, the standard is actually `.`. Your `.profile` is only read by login shells and by some (not all) login managers. However, login managers (such as lightdm) will attempt to read (source) the file using the system's default shell, normally `/bin/sh`. On Debian-derived systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash` and `dash` is a very simple, POSIX-compliant shell that is *not* `bash` and has no knowledge of the `source` keyword.

Therefore, the command is ignored, the file is not sourced and the variable is not defined. To illustrate:

```
$ cat foo
myvar='foo1'
$ source foo
$ echo $myvar
foo1
```

The same thing in `dash`:

```
$ echo $0
dash
$ source foo
dash: 11: source: not found
$ . ~/foo  ## dash needs the full path
$ echo $myvar
foo1
```